# Dry hopping in the keg using a dry hopper

Tags: dry-hop

I've never dry hopped in a corny keg before.  I purchased a dry hopper with a 300 micron screen.
1.  How do you tie the dry hopper so it floats?  I've heard satin dental floss works well?
2.  After I rack and add the dry hops I'm assuming I pressurize the keg.  How much pressure do I add?

Comment: Why do you think the dry hopper device need to float? Any monofilament will do - fishing line is one common/cheap example. Pasteurise in boiled water before use - not critical but can help!

Answer (score 1):

1. I use monofilament and tie to the diptube.  But I use muslin bags
2. as much as you normally do

Comment: What's your process for removing the dry hops after the time period has elapsed (5 - 7 days most likely)?

Comment: I don't remove them.  They stay in until the keg kicks 2-3 months down the road.  I've never found any reason to remove them.